# Help to change the order of bibliography in ezthesis

Tags: bibliographies, spanish

I am working on a thesis with this template that helps you do your thesis in spanish:
http://nokyotsu.com/latex/ezthesis.html

Everything is fine, except that I need my bibliography to be in order of appearance in the text, and the template gives it in alphabetical order.
I don't know how to change the template. It has a cls program called ezthesis.cls, and a bst one called **ezspanish.bst**, which is the one I figured has to be modified. https://github.com/navarroj/ezthesis/blob/master/ezspanish.bst
I tried a couple of things but nothing has worked yet.

I need the bibliography to be in spanish, as it is modified in this template, but I also need it to be in order of appearance, that's why I can't use any other bibliography style like plainnat, etc.

Here's a shortened main file of the template, where it shows the commands used:

```
\documentclass[oneside,numbers,spanish]{ezthesis}
%% Formato de las referencias bibliogr'aficas:
%%   numbers          - numeradas, p.e. [1]
%%   authoryear (*)   - por autor y a'no, p.e. (Newton, 1997)
%%
%% Opciones adicionales:
%%   spanish         - tesis escrita en espa'nol
\author{Juan Antonio Navarro P\'erez}
\title{Ejemplo de una Tesis}
\degree{Doctor en Ciencias}
\supervisor{Nombre de mi Asesor}
\institution{Universidad de Alg\'un Sitio}
\faculty{Escuela de Ingenier\'ia y Ciencias}
\department{Departamento de Sistemas Computacionales}

%% El siguiente comando agrega ligas activas en el documento para las
%% referencias cruzadas y citas bibliogr'aficas. Tiene que ser *la 'ultima*
%% instrucci'on antes de \begin{document}.
\hyperlinking
\begin{document}

 %% # Portada de la tesis #
%% Mirar el archivo "titlepage.tex" para los detalles.
\include{titlepage}

%% # Cap'itulos #
%% Por cada cap'itulo hay que crear un nuevo archivo e incluirlo aqu'i.
%% Mirar el archivo "intro.tex" para un ejemplo y recomendaciones para
%% escribir.
\include{intro}

%% Incluir la bibliograf'ia. Mirar el archivo "biblio.bib" para m'as detales
%% y un ejemplo.
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

Comment: In ezthesis.cls, there are `\bibliographystyle` lines that control which bst file is used. If there's a standard bibtex style you want to use, use that style's name instead of ezspanish.

Comment: Hi! The thing is I need the bibliography to be in spanish, because my document is in this language, but I also need it to be in order of appearance, that's why I can't use any other bibliography style like plainnat, etc. Altough the truth is I tried changing it to another style and couldn't do it either...

Comment: The [spain bibtex style](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/biblio/bibtex/contrib/spain) is also in Spanish. So you should be able to use the same methods of makebst to make a Spanish bibliography. But I've never used makebst in languages other than English.

Comment: An alternative would be to use the modern package `biblatex` with `biber`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this particular case.
On the line 177 of the file ezthesis.cls change:
\bibliographystyle{ezspanish}
by
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
Or the style you prefer and done!
I hope it helps you or someone who was having the same problem.

Comment: Is this not a completely different citation style then? The IEEE Transactions are also supposed to be english to the best of my knowledge.